# Limiting and redirect port access with useragent

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to write iptables *string match* rule To block ***http://domain.com:8888*** and ***https://domain.com:8888*** when it matches the supplied string in the rule. And another rule to redirect the ports also from `8888` to `7777`

I tried following rules but unfortunately didn't work

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m string --string linuxcore --algo bm --sport 8888 -j DROP`

`iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m string --algo bm --string linuxcore -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8888 -j DROP`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8888 -m string --algo bm --string "linuxcore" -j REDIRECT --to-port 7777`

`iptables  -A INPUT -t nat -p tcp --dport 8888 -m string --algo bm --string "linuxcore" -j DROP`

I want to do this from iptables not the webserver because the server may not have a webserver and those ports are working on internal proxy or something like ..etc

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the access to an HTTP service, this can be done on your web server like [apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html). Also, it can be done on a proxy server like squid. However, it is not recommended to filter/deny the traffic based on `User-Agent` as it can be anything. This is stated in the provided link to apache2 documentation.

Firewalls are not designed to filter/deny such a traffic.

Comment: I think it can be done through firewall 

I want a rule like this : 
`iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m string --algo bm --string MyBrowserUserAgent -j Accept` to allow access for port 8888 only for my browseruseragent

Comment: @linuxcore: Yes, it can be done this way. However, it will not be that reliable.

Comment: Please provide me with a rule using iptables *string match*   To block **http://domain.com:8888** and **https://domain.com:8888** when it matches the supplied string in the rule.

And another rule to **allow access** if it only matches the same string.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you want this as a security mechanism, don't -- it's horribly insecure. Rather use HTTP authentication, preferably over SSL.

Secondly, this is a job for your webserver, not the firewall. The implementation would depend on which webserver you're using.

Comment: I think it can be done through firewall 

I want a rule like this : 
`iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m string --algo bm --string MyBrowserUserAgent -j Accept` to allow access for port 8888 only for my browseruseragent

Comment: @linuxcore Yes, technically you could achieve this with iptables, but it's definitely not the Right Way.

Comment: I'm not very clever with iptables. Could you provide me with the full iptables rules to do this and to be similar to the above rule .?

Comment: @linuxcore Just because you *can* do a thing does not mean you *should* do it -- what you're asking for is ***the Wrong Solution***.  In particular: It won't work for SSL-encrypted requests, and it's insecure in every other case anyway.  User-agent-specific handling should be done at the ***APPLICATION*** layer (web server, or website software), not the network layer.

Comment: @voretaq7 You are right But i want to learn how to do this with iptables even if it was the wrong insecure solution.. Please provide me with a rule using iptables *string match*   To block **http://domain.com:8888** and **https://domain.com:8888** when it matches the supplied string in the rule.

And another rule to **allow access** if it only matches the same string.